# pandas Sparse dataframe density issue with fillna

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to create a sparse dataframe in pandas. I create the initial dataframe via

```
df =  pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=db_eng, index_col=index)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], df.index.levels[1]], names=df.index.names)
my_df = df.reindex(idx)
```

and then make that sparse with the following methods

```
s1 = my_df.to_sparse()
s2 = my_df.to_sparse(fill_value=0)
s2 = my_df.to_sparse().fillna(value=0)
```

When I check the density of `s1, s2, s3` I get different values:

```
>>> s1.density
0.054158277796754875
>>> s2.density
1.0
>>> s3.density
0.054158277796754875
```

Why is the second method giving me a density of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to your data, but it looks like your "empty" values are `NaN`, so when making it sparse based on 0 values (i.e. `s2`), then the sparse dataframe is not sparse at all.

This would return what you are expecting:

```
s2 = my_df.fillna(0).to_sparse(fill_value=0)
```

Now your "empty" values are 0s, so calling `to_sparse` with `fill_value=0` actually makes your dataframe sparse.

---

**Edit**: In other words, `to_sparse` will make your dataframe sparse based on the `fill_value`, which is `NaN` by default.

If you call `to_sparse` with `fill_value=0` on a dataframe filled with `NaN` values, then the resulting dataframe is not sparse at all (density = `1.0`), it is full of `NaN` values.

You should read the introduction: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html.

Comment: I don't know if that makes sense. `s2` and `s3` both fill NaNs with 0's but `s3` is still sparse. Also why even have a fill option in the `to_sparse` method if it converts the sparse to dense?

Comment: With `s3` you make it sparse then you fill it with 0's, so it is sparse. With `s2` you fail to make it sparse because you look for 0's instead of `NaN`s. The end result is the same, technically, but one is sparse and the other is not.

Comment: I have added explanations to my answer, if it helps.

Comment: So "empty" values remain empty (in some sense) after the fill? Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: I agree, for me the behaviour of `s3` was the most unexpected! It must be some clever behind-the-scene trick of the `fillna` method for sparse dataframes.